# Ionic Vue: How to update IonSlides when data is updated?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I have some entries that each contain a date:

```
data() {
  return {
    entries: [
      {
        id: 1,
        date: "2020-10-15T14:48:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        date: "2020-12-13T14:48:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        date: "2020-11-28T14:48:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        date: "2020-11-14T14:48:00.000Z",
      },
    ],
  };
},
```

I also have a computed property that extracts the month of each date and adds it to a list if it does not exist yet:

```
computed: {
entriesMonths() {
  // Return an ordered arrays of all months present among entries
  var entriesMonths = [];
  var months_unique = [];
  var current_index = 0;

  const entries = this.entries;

  //Sort entries
  var order = -1;
  entries.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = new Date(a.date);
    b = new Date(b.date);
    var results = a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
    return results * order;
  });

  // Add entry if not present yet
  for (var i in entries) {
    var month = moment(String(entries[i].date)).format("MM");
    var year = moment(String(entries[i].date)).format("YYYY");
    var displayMonth = moment(String(entries[i].date)).format("MMMM YYYY");

    if (!months_unique.includes(displayMonth)) {
      // Push if displayMonth not existent yet
      months_unique.push(displayMonth);
      entriesMonths.push({
        index: current_index,
        month: month,
        year: year,
        displayMonth: displayMonth,
      });
      current_index++;
    }
  }

  return entriesMonths;
}
```

I can display these months with a `v-for` loop

```
<p v-for="month in entriesMonths" :key="month.index">
  <span>{{ month.displayMonth }}</span>
</p>
```

and also add a new entry with a button

```
<ion-button color="primary" @click="add()">
  Add
</ion-button>
```

```
add() {
  const newEntry = {
    id: 5,
    date: "2019-11-14T14:48:00.000Z",
  };
  this.entries.push(newEntry);
},
```

Here the result after clicking the button:

[image]

Instead of in paragraphs I want to display the months in a slider. I can do this like this:

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide v-for="month in entriesMonths" :key="month.index">
    {{ month.displayMonth }}
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

However, when I now press the button, the list gets still updated, but the slider does not. Instead, I get some error message I don't really understand: `DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.`

**How can I update correctly update the slider after adding a new entry?**

For completeness, here is the full code for this example:

```
<template>
  <ion-slides>
    <ion-slide v-for="month in entriesMonths" :key="month.index">
      {{ month.displayMonth }}
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

  <p v-for="month in entriesMonths" :key="month.index">
    <span>{{ month.displayMonth }}</span>
  </p>

  <ion-button color="primary" @click="add()">
    Add
  </ion-button>
</template>

<script>
import { IonButton } from "@ionic/vue";
import { IonSlides, IonSlide } from "@ionic/vue";
import moment from "moment";

export default {
  components: {
    IonSlides,
    IonSlide,
    IonButton,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      entries: [
        {
          id: 1,
          date: "2020-10-15T14:48:00.000Z",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          date: "2020-12-13T14:48:00.000Z",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          date: "2020-11-28T14:48:00.000Z",
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          date: "2020-11-14T14:48:00.000Z",
        },
      ],
    };
  },

  computed: {
    entriesMonths() {
      // Return an ordered arrays of all months present among entries
      var entriesMonths = [];
      var months_unique = [];
      var current_index = 0;

      const entries = this.entries;

      //Sort entries
      var order = -1;
      entries.sort(function(a, b) {
        a = new Date(a.date);
        b = new Date(b.date);
        var results = a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
        return results * order;
      });

      // Add entry if not present yet
      for (var i in entries) {
        var month = moment(String(entries[i].date)).format("MM");
        var year = moment(String(entries[i].date)).format("YYYY");
        var displayMonth = moment(String(entries[i].date)).format("MMMM YYYY");

        if (!months_unique.includes(displayMonth)) {
          // Push if displayMonth not existent yet
          months_unique.push(displayMonth);
          entriesMonths.push({
            index: current_index,
            month: month,
            year: year,
            displayMonth: displayMonth,
          });
          current_index++;
        }
      }

      return entriesMonths;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      const newEntry = {
        id: 5,
        date: "2019-11-14T14:48:00.000Z",
      };
      this.entries.push(newEntry);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot do this using IonSlides, you need to work directly with the underlying library swiperjs - https://swiperjs.com/

Comment: Nice, thanks, that was it! I used `removeAllSlides()` and then a loop around `appendSlide()` to be able to add slides in between.